# One of the "legs" in the circuit box is dead

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm fixing up the back room and after turning off the breaker for that part of the house, I disconnected an outlet high up on the wall (no idea why it was there) and since it was powering the lower outlet, reconnected the power line to the bottom one.

When I turned the breaker back on, there was no power to all the breakers powered by one of the two legs. No issue with the other leg, or the breakers associated with the live one.

Is there any way I could have caused the issue? An electrician is on the way but I'd like to know if anyone else has an opinion. Seems too much of a coincidence but since the breaker was off the entire time I can't imagine what could have happened. Also, no sparks, no burning smell, no heat, no indication of any damage in the box or any of the wiring inside or outside.

Comment: That does sound like a crazy coincidence, but I'd contact the power company about a possible issue on their end. If you feel like you can do it safely, test the voltage of the dead leg at the panel.

Comment: Try turning the main breaker off and back on.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel?